# Is there an established way to identify a DAAP service with UPnP?

Tags: upnp

I've been messing around with media server stuff again, I was wondering if there's a generally agreed-upon way to identify a DAAP server on the network over UPnP. Surely not everyone is counting on people manually punching in their IP address when looking for a server on the network, *right*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAAP is typically advertised on a network using the [ZeroConf protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZeroConf) (AKA: [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)))).  This is pretty much standard since its what iTunes uses and iTunes is by far the biggest implementor of DAAP.  I don't know of any way of advertising DAAP over UPnP.